# Generate particles for spiral galaxy in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, math, random, three.js, spiral

I would like to create a simple spiral galaxy using `THREE.Points` in THEE.js.
 
I cannot figure out how to generate spiral arms. Is there any (not too difficult) way to do this?

Here I created this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76o408qp/1/). There is a flattened sphere but without spiral arms.

```js
const scene = new THREE.Scene()
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight)
camera.position.z = 1500
scene.add(camera)
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ clearColor: 0x000000 })
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)

// Random function with normal dustribution.
const normalRandom = (mean, std) => {
    let n = 0
    
    for (let i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
      n += Math.random()
    }

    return (n - 6) * std + mean
}

const geometry = new THREE.Geometry()
const galaxySize = 1000

// Generate particles for spiral galaxy:
for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  var theta = THREE.Math.randFloatSpread(360) 
  var phi = THREE.Math.randFloatSpread(360)
  const distance = THREE.Math.randFloatSpread(galaxySize)

  // Here I need to generate spiral arms instead of a sphere.
  geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(
    distance * Math.sin(theta) * Math.cos(phi),
     distance * Math.sin(theta) * Math.sin(phi),
     distance * Math.cos(theta) / 10
  ))
}

const spiralGalaxy = new THREE.Points(geometry, new THREE.PointsMaterial({ color: 0xffffff }))
scene.add(spiralGalaxy)

function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render)
    renderer.render(scene, camera)
    spiralGalaxy.rotation.x += 0.01;
    spiralGalaxy.rotation.y += 0.01;
}

render()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/102/three.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you've already done a lot of the heavy lifting yourself, with the polar coordinate system. Keep in mind, however, that the angles are in radians, not in degrees, so instead of using `360`, you should be using `PI * 2`. Now all you have to do is increment both `distance` and `theta` simultaneously to create a spiral, while `phi` remains close to 0 to create the galaxy's ecliptic plane.

- `distance` will grow from `0` to `galaxySize`
- `theta` will grow from `0` to `Math.PI` (or `PI * 2`, if you want tighter spirals)
- `phi` stays close to 0

```js
// Temp variables to assign new values inside loop
var norm, theta, phi, thetaVar, distance;

// Generate particles for spiral galaxy:
for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    // Norm increments from 0 to 1
    norm = i / 1000;

    // Random variation to theta [-0.5, 0.5]
    thetaVar = THREE.Math.randFloatSpread(0.5);

    // Theta grows from 0 to Math.PI (+ random variation)
    theta = norm * Math.PI + thetaVar;

    // Phi stays close to 0 to create galaxy ecliptic plane
    phi = THREE.Math.randFloatSpread(0.1);

    // Distance grows from 0 to galaxySize
    distance = norm * galaxySize;

    // Here I need generate spiral arms instead of sphere.
    geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(
        distance * Math.sin(theta) * Math.cos(phi),
        distance * Math.sin(theta) * Math.sin(phi),
        distance * Math.cos(theta)
    ));
}
```

You could create one loop for each arm. Notice that instead of dividing by 10 at the end, as you did in your example, I simply limited the range of phi to `[-0.1, 0.1]`. You can see it in action [in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/marquizzo/b1dj302o/1/)